# Pluralsight ASP.NET Core 1.0 Fundamentals by Scott Allen- Walk thru failing to work in Visual Studio Community 2017 RC

Tags: asp.net-core

The site shows this.
[image]

Yet My visual studio only shows this...
[image]

I do not see a .addJsonFile option.
the quick use of google says to install Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-*" in my dependencies
Searching in the Dependency Nuget it shows me this
[image]

So my question is what did the new version break; and is there an updated tutorial on the new version?

Comment: Try using the correct case `AddJsonFile`

Comment: i need this course. can you please give if you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. 
Had to click the browse button of the nuget manager
[image]
Then I had to add this line to using
[image]